# entry: displayed text updated only on second loop

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to write procedure that update predefined string displayed in entry.

```
#!/bin/env wish

set tech {A B}
set rules {}

frame .t
ttk::combobox .t.maps -textvariable rules -state readonly -values $tech 
entry .t.e -textvariable base_list 

pack .t .t.maps .t.e 

bind .t.maps <Button-1> {
    switch -- $rules {
        "A" { 
            set base_list {1 2 3}
        }
        "B" { 
            set base_list {4 5 6} 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that string in entry updated only on second combobox value selection.

Example:

GUI start

[image: GUI Start]

Selecting "A"

[image: Selecting A]

The entry is still empty!

Selecting "A" again

[image: SElecting A again]

this time entry was updated

Selecting "B"

[image]

The entry string still not updated to "4 5 6"

Selecting "B" again

[image]

How can I modify my code to make entry be updated on first combobox value selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event instead of `<Button-1>`. Nice side effect: the binding is also called when the user selects combobox items via the keyboard.

```
#!/bin/env wish

set tech {A B}
set rules {}

frame .t
ttk::combobox .t.maps -textvariable rules -state readonly -values $tech 
entry .t.e -textvariable base_list 

pack .t .t.maps .t.e 

bind .t.maps <<ComboboxSelected>> {
    switch -- $rules {
        "A" { 
            set base_list {1 2 3}
        }
        "B" { 
            set base_list {4 5 6} 
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: there's a typo in your example: `tech` must be `$tech` in the `ttk::combobox` line.